# Better way to select view controller using popToViewController: animated:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Consider:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

Is there a better way to get index of the view controller to pop to?  This way if I do something to the nav stack, I don't have to go back and edit this.  I was thinking of maybe storing it in a ivar on the VC or using #define macros.  Any ideas?

**Edit:**
The stack has four view controllers. I used this code to pop from the fourth to the second.

Comment: What defines "the view controller to pop to"?

Comment: He is using the index instead of explicitly passing a reference to the view controller.  This is cool, but it would be nice to not have to hardcode the index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace code in the question with a simple category on `UINavigationController` which can be used wherever it's appropriate.

```
@interface UINavigationController(indexPoping)
- (void)popToViewControllerAtIndex:(NSInteger)newVCsIndex animated:(BOOL)animated;
@end

@implementation UINavigationController(indexPoping)
- (void)popToViewControllerAtIndex:(NSInteger)newVCsIndex animated:(BOOL)useAnimation
{
    if (newVCsIndex < [self.viewControllers count]) {
        [self popToViewController:[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:newVCsIndex] animated:useAnimation];
    }
}


// Usage

...

NSInteger indexToPopTo = ...
[self.navigationController popToViewControllerAtIndex:indexToPopTo animated:YES]

...
```

Comment: I'm geting undeclared identifier for newVCsIndex

Answer (score 5):

```
YourViewController *yourViewController;
for ( UIViewController *viewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers ) {
    if ( [viewController isMemberOfClass:[YourViewController class]] ) {
        yourViewController = (YourViewController*)viewController;
        break;
    }
}

[self popToViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
```

Of course, this assumes the stack will have only one instance of the controller class that you are looking for. If there are more, I think you can choose to store it in a globally accessible location like the application delegate.

---

Note - typically if you are using this in a UIViewController, that final line of code would be:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:seuleMainPage animated:YES];
```

Comment: Fantastically clever idea - good one. I figured just keep it in a singleton (eg the app delegate as you say) but this is such a great solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply using with `isKindOfClass`

```
[self.navigationController.viewControllers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if([obj isKindOfClass:[YourViewController class]]) {
            YourViewController *objVC = obj;
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:objVC animated:YES];
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];
```