# Push UIViewController B from VC A but dealloc VC A once VC B is visible

Tags: ios, iphone

UIViewControllers are always pushed on a stack hierarchy whether it's a modal present or a  UINavigationController push on iPhone. How could I present a UIViewController from another one without having to keep the hierarchy and **Being able to use Transitioning delegate**.

```
VC = UIViewController

VC A on screen
VC A --present--> VC B
VC B on screen
VC A dealloc
VC B --present--> VC C
VC C on screen
VC B dealloc
VC C --present--> VC X (or whatever other)
VC X on screen
VC C dealloc

etc...
```

Comment: Push UIViewController B from VC A => you just need dismiss or popViewController

Comment: Ciao, don't totally understand the question, but is it possible the fantastically clever "Deepak solution" here would help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065479/better-way-to-select-view-controller-using-poptoviewcontroller-animated/6071463#6071463

Answer (score 0):

I just want to said : don't do that ! It's just the way it should append, as when you will have finished with VC B (when user press previous button) you want VC A to be back as it was...

Nethertheless, if for a very good reason you want to process as you explain, I'll propose to have a VC Main that will manage all the other like :

```
VC Main : push VC A
VC A    : Request (delegate) VC Main to show VC B
VC Main : ok, pop VC A + push VC B
VC B    : Request VC Main to show VC X
VC Main : ok, pop VC B + push VC X
VC X    : Request VC main to show VC A
VC Main : ok pop VC X + push VC A (VC A is display as default and not as it was on line 2)
```

Comment: I think it's stupid to have to do this but I'm being paid to do it so i'm trying to find a way. I was trying to implement such architecture but I need to have transitioning delegate make super duper animation from one view controller to the next one like a image becoming full screen while becoming black and white which is just an example!

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is to use UINavigationController delegate. For example you can create your own child of UINavigationController.

MyNavigationViewController.h file:

```
@interface MyNavigationViewController : UINavigationController
@end
```

MyNavigationViewController.m file:

```
@interface MyNavigationViewController () <UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@end

@implementation MyNavigationViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (self.viewControllers.count > 1) {
        self.viewControllers = @[self.topViewController];
    }
}

@end
```

Then just use `MyNavigationViewController` instead of `UINavigationController` in your code!